# Representation finite tensor product algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite dimensional (over a field $K$) algebras such that $A \otimes_K B$ is representation-finite.
Is it true that $A$ or $B$ is a radical square zero algebra?

You may assume that $A$ and $B$ are given by quiver and relations.